# How to show certain content part of the page to Logged in users In Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I can protect the Pages and HTTP resources using ACL, but I want to protect the certain content sections in a page to only logged-in users ? How can this be implemented in Magnolia CMS?

Ex. I want to show the price of the product only to logged in users.

Do we need to create protected and unprotected by duplicating or is there a way of protecting only the Price portion of the content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the template script:

```
[#assign username = (ctx.user.name)! /]
[#assign loggedIn = username?has_content && username != 'anonymous' /]
<div>
  Some unprotected content...
  [#if loggedIn]
    <span class="protected">only for logged in users</span>
  [/#if]
  ... and again unprotected.
</div>
```

Anyway, if you already have a custom model class, I would add an `isLoggedIn()` method, performing the check (you can add more checks there, i.e. whether the user has some required role), and use the following in the template script:

```
<div>
  Some unprotected content...
  [#if model.loggedIn]
    <span class="protected">only for logged in users</span>
  [/#if]
  ... and again unprotected.
</div>
```